# jQuery animate height in different class

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to have height of animate in different class as is in my case ".bar1"???

`$('.bar1').animate({'height':'58%'},1000);`

Just to get idea what I mean: **'.bar_graf'**

`$('.bar1').animate({'.bar_graf'.'height':'58%'},1000);`

Comment: Do you mean animating `.bar2` height to 58% of `.bar_graf` height?

Comment: your question isn't clear at all.. please clarify

Comment: I have a bargraf, and on mouseover I want to show tooltip. But when mouse over .bar1 the tooltip is off by 58% to top, I want to have it just above mouse.

Comment: so you want adjust the height or the position of the tooltip?

Comment: yes I want to adjust position of my tooltip, because it sets by height of bar

Comment: can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your problem?

Comment: @ZoltanToth ok I have made it you can see the problem http://jsfiddle.net/lipcikm/Dun7q/15/

Comment: Take a look - http://jsfiddle.net/Dun7q/17/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div>`-s inside of `<strong>`-s are invalid, so need to fix that

```
<div class="graph">
    <strong class="bar1"></strong>
    <div class="tooltip">18%</div>
</div>
```

Then the tooltip becomes relatively positioned to `.graph` and we can adjust its' vertical position:

```
var my = event.pageY - 100;
```

And the result - http://jsfiddle.net/Dun7q/17/